# Ajax text to PHP duplicates text and button when passing value

Tags: php, ajax

I am working on a bit of ajax that gets the value from a text input and passes it into a php variable. I have got the following code doing what I want, however it duplicates the text input and the button when it passes the value into php and I can't work out why, any ideas:

```
<html><head><title>Ajax Example</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function callAjaxAddition() {
  arguments0 = $("input[name='arg1']").val();
  $.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: "refresh.php",
     data: {arguments: arguments0},
     success: function(data) {
       $("#answer").html(data);    
    }
  });
  return false;
}
</script>
</head>
<body><div id="exampleForm">
     <input name="arg1" /><div id="answer"></div>
     <br />
     <button onClick="callAjaxAddition()">Click Me to Add</button>
</div>
<?php

if(isset($_POST['arguments']))
{
   $a = $_POST['arguments'];

   echo $a;
   var_dump($a);
}
?>
</body></html>
```

Comment: alert the ajax data alert(data);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are sending request to a php file that has html code in it. So it renders current html, it has text box in it. And you are putting it in `answer` div. That's why it is duplicating. If you make a request to refresh.php, it response whole page not only `echo $a;` part. Create aseparate page like `service.php` and

**service.php**:

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['arguments']))
{
   $a = $_POST['arguments'];

   echo $a;
}
?>
```

Use `service.php` in your ajax call